# use query string for href

Tags: vb.net, query-string, anchor, href

Should be simple, but can't figure out how to do it.

Want:

```
<a href="/sites/folder/page.aspx?variable=123456">Test</a>
```

By:

```
<a href="/sites/folder/page.aspx?variable=<% Request.QueryString("variable1") %>">Test</a>
```

I've tried `<%#` and `<%=` not expecting either of them to work, but trying them out.  Any ideas or pointers?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe:

```
<a href='/sites/folder/page.aspx?variable=<%= Request.QueryString("variable1") %>'>
```

or (imo) use a protected or public property (is that the same in Vb?) in the code behind, then you can do:

```
<a href="/sites/folder/page.aspx?variable=<%= Variable1 %>">
```

which I think looks better, plus you can add logic in the code behind: does the value exist? set a default etc...

Comment: I like the idea of the protected property, but due to the size of the project and since my task doesn't define it, I'll just use the query string since it's already there.  :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's the quotation marks that might screw this one up.  Change to the following:

```
<a href='/sites/folder/page.aspx?variable=<%= Request.QueryString("variable") %>'>
```

Comment: I assumed you meant Request.QueryString("variable") and not "variable1".

Comment: Eh, it was just stuff I threw in there to keep the actual names and stuff out of it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) for this

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, but what advantages does a LinkButton give me over an anchor tag?  Just curious.  Thanks.

Comment: It gives you a lot more control over server side functionality without messing about with in-line variables.  It basically promotes separation of concerns between presentation and logic.